# Pandas dataframe not formatting correctly

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, jupyter, conda

I have an issue with jupyter notebook and lab, where the dataframe will load correctly, and work fine, however any sort of formatted output print will give an error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\formatters.py in __call__(self, obj)
343             method = get_real_method(obj, self.print_method)
344             if method is not None:
--> 345                 return method()
346             return None
347         else:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _repr_html_(self)
647         # display HTML, so this check can be removed when support for
648         # IPython 2.x is no longer needed.
--> 649         if console.in_qtconsole():
650             # 'HTML output is disabled in QtConsole'
651             return None

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\Test\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\console.py in in_qtconsole()
121             ip.config.get('KernelApp', {}).get('parent_appname', "") or
122             ip.config.get('IPKernelApp', {}).get('parent_appname', ""))
--> 123         if 'qtconsole' in front_end.lower():
124             return True
125     except NameError:

AttributeError: 'LazyConfigValue' object has no attribute '
```

I've looked everywhere for even something similarish, can't find anything with a 'LazyConfigValue' anywhere.

I've reinstalled in new environments, uninstalled and reinstalled anaconda, but i'm getting the same issue everytime.

Anyone have any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Can you show us the data+code so we can replicate?

Comment: I found some error when using spacy + pandas. Could it be your case? See: [link](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4369)

Comment: @Lukas yes this must be it [I just saw this](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3208) after you said that. Thank you, never would have thought to check Spacy!

Answer (score 1):

Caused due to Spacy package import, as suggested by @Lukas

[Spacy Issue](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/3208)